# validation in angular form not showing error message while validating ipaddress

Tags: angular, angular-forms, form-control

I am using Formcontrol thing  in angular , in this  I am not able to see error message -this is code-snippet whatever I am trying

app.component.html

```
<div>
<form [FormGroup]="abcGroup" (validSubmit)="updateDnsData()>

        <div class="form-group row" >
            <label for="primaryDns" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label text-right">Primary DNS:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control-sm border border-2 border-dark" formcontrolName="primaryDns"  id="primaryDns"
                    value="{{primaryDns}}">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
ngOninIt(){
this.abcFormGroup();
}
abcFormGroup(){
  this.abcGroup = this.fb.group({
   
  primaryDns:["", [
         Validators.required,
         Validators.pattern(/((?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){3}(?:[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/)
  })
}
```

in updateDnsData()  , I am using put method

I need to validate Ipaddress, I wrote regex for ipaddress validation using formcontrol in angular , here the validation does not working, any help would be appreciated

Comment: what do you expect to happen? do you see any error in JS console?

Comment: i want to show error(invalid-ip address) near to text box , i do not find any error in console

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a message/warning whenever the entered value does not match you pattern:

```
<p *ngIf="abcGroup.get('primaryDns').hasError('pattern')">The entered address is invalid</strong>
```

If you like to disable a submit button until the form becomes valid:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!abcGroup.valid">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be sure that you are importing ReactiveFormsModule and also use correct spelling for directives, in your case it's [formGroup], not [FormGroup]. Same error with formControlName